# ASP.NET Core Mvc how to pass query params by default to named HttpClients?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string, base-url, httpclientfactory

I have a preconfigured base url for my named HttpClientFactory, but I also want to pass an api_key as query param to it by default, are there options to do it, or how would I do it in general?

```
//Just some setup stuff here...
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("https://localhost:5003");
... add Services
var mvcBuilder = builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
```

how to add query params?

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(name: "MoviesDBClient", 
    configureClient: options =>
    {
    options.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/");
    options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(
    "application/json", 1.0));
    });
```

because the `api.themoviedb.org` requires my api_key and I don't want to append it to the url every time again...

Comment: pass API key in headers

Comment: Hmmm, not quite understand what you try to achieve. You want something like read the api key from config file and programmatically append to API url?

Comment: You will have to append it to the URL each time. Looking at their documentation I don't see a great way around it. Sessions don't last forever so you wouldn't want to bake it into the base url anyway.

Comment: @UpenderReddy I'm not sure if that will work, because in the docs, they say I would have to pass it as query param in the url or is it basically the same as in the headers? Because there is not Authorization Header like Bearer token or so

Comment: @YongShun yeah, that would be the "usual" way to do it I guess.. but in C# ASP.net there exists named HttpCLients from HttpClientFactory, so I thought I could also pre-configure my Client statically in a way that the query param is always "baked in" at the end of the request line so to say..

Comment: @Crowcoder ok I guess that's fine with me then